# Quaternion Components to Float (Eigen)

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions

I have an `Eigen::Quaternion` and I want to convert it's 
components `x, y, z, w` to `double`.

A simple assignment like this is not working because the components are of type `Scalar`. This is what I tried:

```
Eigen::Quaternion<float> q;
q = Eigen::AngleAxis<float>(2, Eigen::Vector3f(0,0,1));
float x = q.x;
```

The documentation of the `Scalar` type is weak. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scalar` is not a datatype but a template argument of [`Eigen::Quaternion`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html).

So if you declare `Eigen::Quaternion<float> q` this means for this quaternion, `Scalar` is set to `float`.

What you were missing in your example code is that to extract the `x` component you must call a **method** named [`x()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html#a5eb2596dc2a509b276d01578a9c3dd27).

The following example shows how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Geometry> 

int main()
{
  Eigen::Quaternion<float> q;
  q = Eigen::AngleAxis<float>(2, Eigen::Vector3f(0,0,1));
  float x = q.x();

  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```